# Prevent schema change from wiping out db of a play framework 2 project

Tags: mysql, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm using Play Framework 2 with EBean and MySQL for the database. When a member of any of my model classes is changed, it creates a db evolution, and play wants to wipe out the old database.

Does anybody know a good process for preserving the old db values when the schema is updated and evolutions are run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start writing evolutions scripts manually, as described [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Evolutions)

Assuming you are using the ebean plugin you also need to stop DDL generation via application.conf like so `evolutionplugin=disabled`